# CellForRowAtIndexPath not called - UITableViewCells disappear/are blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

*Posting a specific question/answer to a specific problem (unlike the general problems with this method I've seen elsewhere):*

I have a `UITableView`, which is a part of a custom `UITableViewController`, which I setup and then add to a different view controller.

My `UITableView` is being loaded, calls all the appropriate setup methods (e.g. numberOfRowsInSection, numberOfSectionsInTableView, etc), **but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never called.**

I've confirmed that the dataset is being loaded - `numberOfRowsInSection` is not always zero.

What gives??

Comment: This is specific, and also oft-repeated.  9 times out of 10 the tableview datasource is not set.

Comment: Your datasource is empty

Comment: @danh - If this is a duplicate of a known question/answer, I'm happy to delete - was just very surprised to find that even though I had a strong reference to a child object of the view controller, the view controller was still being killed.

Comment: It certainly isn't a duplicate of the standard problem that it first appeared to be.  But you may be misunderstanding both memory management and norms for managing view controllers and their views.

Comment: @danh - agreed, if I had thought more critically about the reference chain I probably wouldn't have ended up here. But I was certainly led astray by the fact that "the rest" of the tableView delegate methods were being called, even when at the end of it cellForRow wasn't called. There's probably another point to consider - whether or not "I missed a situation where ARC deleted stuff I wanted to keep" posts are worth having around for specifics, since they could endlessly proliferate - my thinking was that this was weird enough to post as it could help others with the same mindset as me.

Comment: I think there's a better answer available, one that gets more to the root cause of the problem, which is the unusual means of reusing table view logic by moving the actual view between vcs.  There's a simpler and normative way to reuse datasource logic which is to realize that datasources needn't be view controllers.

Comment: Are you using a custom `UITableViewCell`? If so, you might want to check that your prototype cell specifies the class for the `UITableViewCell`. You might want to post your `viewDidLoad` from your `UITableViewController` along w/ the methods you say are returning values. How are you determining they return values?

Comment: @danh - Interesting - I'm certainly no old-pro, would you suggest the same design for a situation where the "master datasource" is responsible for multiple tableViews? This is my case - off the cuff, I just don't know of an easy way to identify which tableView it is that is calling the master datasource.

Comment: The datasource methods offer the tableView as the first parameter.  Most of the time, if you want the tables (sharing that datasource) to look the same, you don't even need it.  Will post the idea, in brief, in a few mins

Comment: @danh - that would be great, and a worthwhile refactor - I'd be able to delete 4 custom VCs from my codebase (at the cost of making one logic file very long..). BTW the tables don't look very similar - I'll look into using the tableView as an ID either way

Comment: @AdrianB - I already posted my solution (so I don't actually have a problem now), but yep I'm sure that my custom cell is being loaded from the nib & is registered to a reuse ID in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: didn't notice YOU posted the solution :) I figured there would be a green checkmark if you'd figured it out.

Comment: @Sitric - posted what I would characterize as the normative way to accomplish a shared datasource.  Building another view controller and keeping it around can work as you're seeing, but I'd liken it to buying a car because you want to listen to its radio.   Just buy a radio :-)

Answer (score 1):

The goal appears to be the reuse of a table view's datasource.  This can be accomplished by separating the datasource from the view controller.  In outline, as follows:

```
// MyTableViewDatasource.h
@interface MyTableViewDatasource : NSObject <UITableViewDatasource> 

@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;

@end

// MyTableViewDatasource.m

#import "MyTableViewDatasource.h"

@implementation MyTableViewDatasource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)s {
    return self.array.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // your cell config logic from the original view controller
    // replace any mention of that vc's model array with self.array
}

@end
```

Now, say ViewControllerA has a tableView, and we want its datasource to be our newly defined datasource...

```
// ViewControllerA.m

#import "ViewControllerA.h"
#import "MyTableViewDatasource.h"

@interface ViewControllerA ()

@property(strong,nonatomic) MyTableViewDatasource *datasource;

@end

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // create our data and our datasource
    // don't have to do this in viewDidLoad, but it needs to be done
    // before the table can be seen, anytime after the model is ready
    // this "model" in your case is whatever array that holds the data for the table
    NSMutableArray *model = [@[@"Moe", @"Larry", @"Curly"] mutableCopy];

    MyTableViewDatasource *datasource = [[MyTableViewDatasource alloc] init];
    datasource.array = model;
    self.tableView.datasource = datasource;
}
```

Now ViewControllerA, wherever it once modified its model array, should do the same this way...

```
[self.datasource.array addObject:@"Shemp"];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Hopefully it's clear that ViewControllerB and C and so on can do the same thing, replacing the code that you posted in your answer.

Comment: +1 This definitely works,  though the upvote is going to be confusing based on the original question - perhaps I'll modify later. I very likely will end up just doing a "tableView" object comparison to a property in the VC (& just hold as many tableView properties as I need tableViews) and let it continue being the master datasource. However, if that starts to get unwieldy (dataSource methods get stuffed with comparison logic + actual setup logic), then I'll segregate out the datasources. Thanks for the help/ideas! My compile time is going to be very happy

Comment: I think a good way to evolve the code is by starting out with if-else logic, then as it matures, parceling it out into variations of MyTableViewDatasourceA, B, C, etc.  Remember that relating these to each other as subclass-superclass is another linguistic tool available to you, and another good reason to isolate the datasource logic from the vcs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC, then it's very likely that your custom view controller, which is the ultimate **owner** of your UITableView, it being trashed as soon as you add the tableView to another view.

Try adding the UITableView's view controller to the master/other view controller's, either via a property or through the view hierarchy.

In my case, I simply created a new property for it in the view controller that wanted its table:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyTableViewController *tvc;
```

and later assigned it to self when creating it:

```
self.tvc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
[self.someOtherView addSubview:tvc.tableView];
```